# loading webpages in iframe don't start spinning circle

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I have a web page with multiple iframes. In Google Chrome, when I click in one iframe a link to load in another it doesn't start the blue spinner circle on the tab of the browser. That was working until this week and is anoying that if it takes 10 secs to load the user doesn't see it, and think that needs to click on the link again.

Is there a chrome new policy on this or a fix I can use to start and stop the spinner?

I cleaned the browser history with no effect, and the webpage code hasn't change.

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing for the past week!

Answer (score 0):

This is a change that the Chromium dev team has done on purpose, and are not planning on changing it back:

Here is the discussion where they have essentially said that this is not a bug, and will not be fixed:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769803#c8

They've essentially said that it's a feature request. Perhaps if enough people request it, they will change it back?